About the integral $ \int_a^b h(u-y) \, \exp\left(2\pi i \mu (uz-y)-2\pi i \nu y\right) \, dy $
I have an integral that I'd like to estimate or approximate in some way. The integral is given by:
$$ \int_a^b h(u-y) \, \exp\left(2\pi i \mu (uz-y)-2\pi i \nu y\right) \, dy $$
where the parameters $a$, $b$, $\nu$, $z$, and $u$ are all finite real numbers. The function $h$ is integrable and tends to zero at infinity, although this latter property might not be of much use since the integral is defined over a finite interval $[a, b]$.
I wouyld like to estimate or approximate this integral. Are there known approaches or transformations to address the analysis of this integral?
Any suggestions or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Does $h$ have any singularities? Since your description of $h$ is that vague, I suppose the most general approach is developing $h$ as a power series in $y$ (once applying the substitution $u-y\to y$) around some point $y_0$ which lies between $[u-b,u-a]$

@Conreu, you are right, Sorry. Function $h$ does not have any singularities and is smooth

We can rearrange your integrand a bit like this
$$\exp(2\pi i\mu u z)\int_a^b h(u-y)\exp[-2\pi i(\mu+\nu)y]\,\mathrm dy$$
Now we may apply substitution like $u-y\to y$ in turn obtaining
$$\exp[-2\pi i(\mu(1-z)+\nu)u]\int_{u-a}^{u-b} h(y)\exp[2\pi i(\mu+\nu)y]\,\mathrm dy$$
Since $h$ is analytical everywhere we can expand it around the origin (for simplicity purposes) and it'll still cover the interval $[u-b,u-a]$:
$$\exp[-2\pi i(\mu(1-z)+\nu)u]\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n\int_{u-a}^{u-b} y^n\exp[2\pi i(\mu+\nu)y]\,\mathrm dy$$
Finally that integral can be expressed in terms of exponential integral functions, $\mathrm E_{-n}(\cdot)$, like so:
$$\small \exp[-2\pi i(\mu(1-z)+\nu)u]\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n\left\{(u-a)^{n+1}\mathrm E_{-n}[-2\pi i(\mu+\nu)(u-a)]-(u-b)^{n+1}\mathrm E_{-n}[-2\pi i(\mu+\nu)(u-b)]\right\}$$

Another way to approach it would be noticing that
$$\int_{u-a}^{u-b} h(y)\exp[2\pi i(\mu+\nu)y]\,\mathrm dy=\mathscr F_y\left\{\left[\theta(u-a)-\theta(u-b)\right]h(y)\right\}(-\mu-\nu),\enspace \mu,\nu<0$$
and so your integral is just
$$\exp[-2\pi i(\mu(1-z)+\nu)u]\mathscr F_y\left\{\left[\theta(u-a)-\theta(u-b)\right]h(y)\right\}(-\mu-\nu)$$
So maybe you can approximate the Fourier Transform via some other methods.
